# Cut off element with float parent and float and non-float siblings in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

The following code does not behave as I expect:

```
<!doctype html>
<title>Test case</title>
<div style="float: left">
    <div style="float: left;">Short.</div>
    <div></div>
    <div style="overflow: hidden;">ALongText.</div>
</div>
```

In Chrome (44.0.2403.107 m) this looks like:

```
Short.ALon
```

I would assume that the parent div would accomodate the size of all three children:

```
Short.ALongText.
```

Or the third div would be pushed down, because it does not fit:

```
Short.
ALongText.
```

**Why does Chrome cut off the div?**

Note that the width of the parent element is equal to the "natural size" of last child div, excluding the floating child.

Comment: why you are not using  display: inline-block? or you can delete the div between the two inner divs

Answer (score 1):

The parent Div will not accommodate the size of all three children. The reason for this is the parent div is floated to left. In case of a floated element when no width is given to that element it will take its max child's width, the child that has the max width. In your case the last element is the child with max width. I have recreated the following examples to illustrate this concept better. 
https://jsfiddle.net/osha90/rk2jc89f/

```
<div style="color:black"><!-- No float-->
<div style="float: left;">Short.</div>
<div></div>
<div style="overflow:hidden">ALongText.</div>
</div>

 <div style="float:left;color:red"><!-- First element has max width -->
<div style="float: left;">ALongText.</div>
<div></div>
<div style="overflow:hidden">Short.</div>
</div>

 <div style="float:left;color:green"><!-- Second element has max width -->
<div style="float: left;">Short.</div>
<div></div>
<div style="overflow:hidden">ALongText.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please always specify width when using floats.

Comment: You say that the parent will be as wide as the widest child. But if I remove the middle div, it is as wide as required to accomodate both divs.

Comment: Why should I always specify width on floats?

Comment: The reason the above happens is because of Block Formatting Context.

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the empty DIV

```
<title>Test case</title>
<div style="float: left">
    <div style="float: left;">Short.</div>
    <div style="overflow: hidden;">ALongText.</div>
</div>
```

or add float left to the same DIV

```
<div style="float: left">
    <div style="float: left;">Short.</div>
    <div style="float: left;"></div>
    <div style="overflow: hidden;">ALongText.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: The question is a very simplified version of a website I'm working on, so I can't really do that. My question is really to understand why it why it acts as it does.

Comment: The structure is very wrong, floating left the parent is not allowing the browser to calculate the width in the right way. You can try to remove the float:left of the parent and the browser in this way calculate the inner divs width in the right way @propeller

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#block-formatting:

> Floats [...] and block boxes with 'overflow' other than 'visible' [...] establish new block formatting contexts for their contents.
>
> In a block formatting context, boxes are laid out one after the other, vertically, beginning at the top of a containing block. The vertical distance between two sibling boxes is determined by the 'margin' properties. [...]
>
> In a block formatting context, each box's left outer edge touches the left edge of the containing block [...]. This is true even in the presence of floats [...], unless the box establishes a new block formatting context (in which case the box itself [*may* become narrower due to the floats](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#bfc-next-to-float)).

The third box establishes a new context, so the linked section tells us:

> [...] an element in the normal flow that establishes a new block formatting context (such as an element with 'overflow' other than 'visible') must not overlap the margin box of any floats in the same block formatting context as the element itself. If necessary, implementations should clear the said element by placing it below any preceding floats, but may place it adjacent to such floats if there is sufficient space. **They may even make the border box of said element narrower** than defined by section 10.3.3. **CSS2 does not define when a UA may put said element next to the float or by how much said element may become narrower.**

In this case Chrome (arbitrarily) decided to make the element narrower instead of clearing it. You can make Chrome change it's mind by for example removing the second div or changing the padding of the third element.